# Form validation returning runtime errors

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

I am trying to connect my front end form to my backend. I have confirmed via Postman that my backend form validation is working but when I press the submit button I get a bunch of runtime errors. I have used the cors middleware in my index.js also so that is not the problem. Here is my index.js:

```
import express from "express";
import { router as UserRouter } from "./Routes/CreateUser.js";
import { mongodbURL, findFoodItems } from "./db.js";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World");
});

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type"]
}));

app.use('/user', UserRouter);

mongoose.connect(mongodbURL)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Database connected");
        app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
            console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

CreateUser.js is:

```
import { User } from "../models/User.js";
import express from "express";
import {body, matchedData, validationResult } from "express-validator";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

const router = express.Router();

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

router.post("/createUser",
    jsonParser,
    [
        body('name', 'Minimum length of name should be 5').isLength({ min: 5 }),
        body('email', 'Invalid email').isEmail(),
        body('password', 'Minimum length of password should be 5').isLength({min: 5}),
        body('location', 'Invalid location').isIn(['India', 'USA'])
    ],
    async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const result = validationResult(req);
            const data = matchedData(req);
            if(result.isEmpty())
            {
                await User.create({
                    name: data.name,
                    password: data.password,
                    email: data.email,
                    location: data.location
                });
                res.json({ success: true });
            }
            else
            {
                res.send({errors: result.array()});
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.json({success: false});
        }   
    });

export { router };
```

And I CreateUser.js is basically the backend part of the form. In my frontend I am using React JS to handle submitting of the form. This is my front end part where I try to link it together with the backend:

SignUp.jsx is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function SignUp() {

    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
        name: "",
        password: "",
        email: "",
        geolocation: ""
    });

    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/user/createUser", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ name: credentials.name, email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password, location: credentials.geolocation })
        });
        const json = await response.json();
        if (!json.success) {
            alert("Enter valid credentials");
        }
    }

    function handleInputChange(event) {
        const { name: inputName, value: newValue } = event.target;

        setCredentials((prevCredentials) => {
            return ({
                ...prevCredentials,
                [inputName]: newValue
            });
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className='container container-color1 m-5 p-5 '>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="name" className='text-color1'>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control mb-3" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" name="name" value={credentials.name} onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="email" className='text-color1'>Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control mb-3" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" value={credentials.email} onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="password" className='text-color1'>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control mb-3" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" value={credentials.password} onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="address" className='text-color1'>Address</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control mb-3" id="address" placeholder="Enter address" name="geolocation" value={credentials.geolocation} onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn button-style">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SignUp;
```

Basically I am giving invalid credentials on purpose so I get an alert saying that my credentials are invalid. However when I click Submit I get runtime errors:

Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
at handleSubmit (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1430:28)

and a bunch of other runtime errors. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have configured CORS correctly on your server (Express) to allow requests from your React application's domain (http://localhost:3000).

```
 app.use(cors({
    //pass frontend url like this to connect frontend with backend
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
        allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type"]
    }));
```

Comment: Yes you are right thank you before I had configured CORS to access from the server localhost:5000 instead of the React application localhost:3000 thank you.